# Create a full screen RelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout

I need to create a full screen RelativeLayout programmatically like the gray background of dialogs (it's on the top of every views).

I try this but ActionBar is above on that:

```
rlContainerLayout = new RelativeLayout(activity);
rlContainerLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));
rlContainerLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.color_gray));
activity.addContentView(rlContainerLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

so how can i achieve something like dialogs background ?

Comment: do you want to use this layout background of dialog? I don't understand whats your need?

Comment: To hide actionbar you can try `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: Edit your question...with any picture ...or details of your problem and also what's wrong with your current code..?

Answer (score 2):

try this before creating Layout.

```
 setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

    create and add your Views here
```